# jUnit comparing XML strings fails even though the XMLs are the same

Tags: java, xml, servlets, junit

I am writing a series of jUnit tests to ensure my proxy Servlet which fetches XMLs for a client page from a variety of sources.

One of my tests send a request to the servlet to fetch the XML and then compares it to a local copy which is the same (I think)

I examined the length of each XML which was quite interesting.

**Local Copy length = 1753**

**Remote Version Length = 1796**

I am just using an assertTrue()

```
assertTrue(remote.equals(local));
```

Any ideas why there is a difference in the length, is there a way in jUnit I can compare the XMLs to ensure they are what is expected and are syntactically correct?

Any other suggestions welcome?

Comment: Maybe there are different linebreak characters in the String, like one time `\n\r` and `\n` only in the other string? If you have 43 lines in your XML that would make sense :)

Comment: Try unmarshal two XMLs and compare the unmarshalled objects.

Comment: @baraky ; I am not familiar with this concept of unmarshalling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your question of better ways to compare XML's - I have previously used [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) and feel that it works out well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that you have different linebreak characters, like `\n` in one String and `\n\r` in the other String. You can remove all linebreaks before you compare the Strings:

```
s1 = s1.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
s2 = s2.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
assertEquals(s1, s2); // should evaluate to true now
```